# Using nodejs/electron to add new line causing multiple lines to be added

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

My code is having a strange behavior. So I have a check box, and when ever the file is checked, it add a new line with new text

```
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
      if (checkbox.checked) {

        console.log('Checked');

        var logStream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/Users/solars/Desktop/myFile.txt', { flags: 'a' });
        // use {flags: 'a'} to append and {flags: 'w'} to erase and write a new file
        logStream.end('\nthis is the end line');

      }
```

But what happens here is:

1. The first time it is checked, a new line would appear with "this is the end line'"
2. I would then uncheck, nothing happens as expected
3. I would recheck and three new lines would appear of "this is the end line'" (all together of 4 lines of "this is the end line')
4. I would then uncheck, nothing happens as expected
5. I would recheck and five new lines would appear of "this is the end line'" (all together of 9 lines of "this is the end line')

I believe it is looping somewhere and when it unchecks it adds one to the number of lines to add (if that makes sense)

Any ideas how to fix this?

The whole code:

```
  <div class="main">
    <h1> click me </h1>
    <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn">
      <div class="slider round"></div>
    </label>

    <script>
      src = "./renderer.js";
      const replace = require('replace-in-file');
      //const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
      var fs = require('fs');
      var array = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/solars/Desktop/myFile.txt').toString().split("\n");
      var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');
      var arrayCheck = array.includes("triangle=3")
      //checkbox.checked = (arrayCheck) ? true : checkbox.checked
      document.getElementById("togBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {


        checkbox.addEventListener('change', function () {
          if (checkbox.checked) {

            console.log('Checked');

            var logStream = fs.createWriteStream('C:/Users/solars/Desktop/myFile.txt', { flags: 'a' });
            // use {flags: 'a'} to append and {flags: 'w'} to erase and write a new file
            logStream.end('\nthis is the end line');

          } else {

            console.log('Not checked');
            //code that set tiangle to  equal 3

          }
        });


      });
    </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: Remove the click listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code says "Every time `togBtn` is clicked, add a listener to `checkbox` that will be executed when it `change`s."

Click the button five times - you add five `change` listeners to `checkbox`. Every single listener will run when the checkbox changes state, and the more times you click `togBtn`, the more times the listener function will run in the future.

To fix, you need to structure your code in a way that you can *never* add more than one listener unless you really, really need to (unlikely). This will certainly involve moving the `change` listener outside of the `click` listener.